# Backbone.js routing depending on model value

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, url-routing

I have a collection that looks something like this

```
[
    {
        "year": 1868,
        ....
           ]
    },
    {
        "year": 1872,
        ....
    },
    {
        ...
    }
]
```

Is there a way to set a route either with `'/year/:year': 'year'` or `'/(:year)': 'year'` ?

I have tried making a lookup table in the main App view, which passes the year index to the model views. I have tried using _.map, _.each, _.pluck and _.where but I guess I must be doing something wrong.

[Here](http://amejias101.github.com/animated-elections/) is a non Backbone view of what it looks like. So navigating to /(:year) would go straight to that year, which corresponds to an model index

**Edit**: to clarify, basically I want the user to be able to go to `/year/:year`, but `:year` value corresponds to a certain model (see above). In this case going to `/year/1868`, would render the first model from the above collection.

**EDIT #2**: Here is how my app looks like.

this is the router
    var router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            '': 'root',
            'year(/:year)': 'year'
        },

```
    root: function() {
        new App();
    },

    year: function(year) {
        new App({
            year: year
        });
    }
});
```

which calls this file

```
define(['backbone', 'assets/js/collections/elections.js', 'assets/js/views/election.js', 'jqueryui'], function(Backbone, Elections, ElectionView, simpleSlider) {
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    current_election_index: 0,
    active_btn_class: 'dark_blue_bg',
    wiki_base: 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_election,_',
    started: 0,
    el: 'body',
    playback: {
        id: '',
        duration: 1750,
        status: false
    },

    initialize: function() {
        elections = new Elections();
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.listenTo(elections, 'reset', this.render);
        elections.fetch();
        this.remove_loader();
    },

    render: function () {
        if (this.started === 0) {
            this.election_year();
        }
        var view = new ElectionView({
            model: elections.at(this.current_election_index),
            election_index: this.current_election_index
        });
        this._make_slider();
        this.update_ui();
        return this;
    },
```

I took out some of the methods, since they are non essential.

Comment: Can you try to clarify your problem? It's a bit hard to parse from your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

A typical solution would looks something like this:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    "year(/:year)" : "electionByYear"
  },

  electionByYear: function(year) {

    //all of your data, wherever you get it from
    var results = this.allElectionResults;

    //if a year parameter was given in the url
    if(year) {
        //filter the data to records where the year matches the parameter
        results = _.findWhere(results, { year: parseInt(year, 10)});
    }

    doSomething(results);

  }
});
```

**Edit based on comments:** If your view is responsible for creating the collection, you should move the above logic to your view, and simply pass the `year` parameter to your view as an argument:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(options) {
    this.year = options.year;
  }
});

var view = new View({year:year});
view.render();
```

Or if you're using an existing view:

```
view.year = year;
view.render();
```

Comment: What is data? and how can the router have access to the collection upon creation? Right now the `root` route is making the view, which then calls on collections.fetch(). I tried doing a console.log(collection.at(0), and I'm getting `undefined`

Comment: @alme1304, sorry, the `data` was just a typing error. I meant to type `results`. Edited that now. I'm also not quite sure what the problem with the `collection` is, but added some suggestions to the answer as well.

Comment: not sure where you wanted me to place the code and I'm still not able to use _.findWhere, I keep getting undefined. I have also added more code to clear everything